# swift - tableview EXC_BREAKPOINT crash

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a basic `tableview` setup, which I load JSON data.
I am using Fabric for crash reports, I tried to replicate the crash but I could guess the scenario from the crash report.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let id = newID
    API.sharedInstance.loadList(id, callback: { (list) in
         if let data = list["objects"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
            self.jsonData = data
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.loadingView?.removeFromSuperview()
          }
    })      
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 return 1 
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.jsonData?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
            cell.yazar = self.jsonData?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

Crash report:

```
 #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10111e588 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt) -> () + 44
    1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100ff7654 specialized _ArrayBuffer.getElement(Int, wasNativeTypeChecked : Bool) -> A + 270
    2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10100db30 Array.subscript.getter + 112
    3  yazar.io                       0x10021c4d0 GazetininYazarlariTableViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (CustomViewController.swift:290)
```

edit: in my tableviewcell

```
var yazar:JSON?{
       didSet{
           self.setupYazar()
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cell.yazar` is of a different type (`Int`) than `self.jsonData?[indexPath.row]` (`Bool`).

Comment: yazar in my cell is also json. Edited the code in my question.

Comment: Please log out `self.jsonData?[indexPath.row]` and post code for `self.setupYazar()`